# How to delete a file uploaded by FileUploader UI Component without submitting the form

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform, file-upload

I have prepared an admin form containing a file upload field. This form is configured in an .xml form file.

```
<field name="files" formElement="fileUploader" sortOrder="40">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Files</item>
            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string">Maximum file size: 50MB. Allowed file types: PDF.</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="isMultipleFiles" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">pdf</item>
            <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">52428800</item>
            <item name="placeholderType" xsi:type="string">document</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="my_custom/route/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

When I click upload and select a file, the file is uploaded and saved to the server and it works fine. Responsible for this is the route set in the .xml file.
[image]
How can I delete a file from the server when I click the trash button in the lower left corner of the file icon? Now clicking the trash button removes the file from the form but not from the server, so I have to submit the form to remove the file from the server, but what if the user opens a new form and submits the file and then leaves the form without saving. The uploaded file will still exist on the server. I thought of sending a request when the trash icon is clicked to a specific route that will be responsible for deleting the file eg. my_custom/route/deletefile. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this? I am using Magento version 2.4.4.

Comment: Hello Quba i have used your code and on my side this works perfect when I have delete the image from the form then also delete from the database, can you please look into that

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, it works perfectly when the form is submitted. The file is deleted from the server and database. However, I want to delete the file after clicking the trash button without submitting the form. I'm talking about a situation where the user submits the wrong file and then uploads the correct file, and the wrong file will still exist on the server because the upload process is done when the user clicks the "Upload" button.